# Every cut is the union of (edge-disjoint) minimal cuts

Tags: graph-theory, decision-theory

I am tasked with proving the following statement:

*"Every cut is the union of edge-disjoint minimal cuts"*

The only information given, is the existance of the cut-set subspace $W_S(G)$. It seems I have to say something about the fact that $W_S(G)$ is a subspace, thus closed under addition, and then proceed to show that the sum of minimal cut vectors is again a cut.

However, I cannot seem to get how this statement would be true, given a graph with a bridge. In that case, there is only one minimal cut (removing the bridge), but there are numerous other cuts that are clearly not unions of this one minimal cut.

Am I seeing it wrong?

Comment: Minimal is not minimum, a minimal cut means that if you remove any edge to a cut, it will no longer be a cut. A minimal cut may not be optimal (but you can see it as "locally optimal"). Here, you can suppose that your cut contains two overlapping minimal cuts and show that these cuts must be equal (hint: take the intersection)